# Find a document that its name contains a letter or a string in mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

Hello I'm implementing a searching functionality in mongodb node js / react native ! I want whenever I type a letter in the searching input I want the backend to fetch documents that has that letter or string in there name ! I can do it the javascript way by fetching all the products then doing it with js but that wouldn't be a good user friendly ! so any suggestion ! make be a query like $contains or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex in your find query to achieve this functionality

To find documents that **starts with** a letter(s)

```
db.collection.find( { name: { $regex: /^test/i } } )
```

This will fetch all the documents where the **name** starts with **test**

To find documents that **contains** letter(s)

```
db.collection.find( { name: { $regex: /test/i } } )
```

Also you can remove **i** from the end if you want case sensitive results.

Comment: It works thank you , another question , when i wanted to add that name as a variable inside the regex , it wont work ! but if i pass the name directly to regex it does ! maybe my way of putting a variable inside a regex doesnt work ? !   ```  let newReg = new RegExp(`/${req.query.name}/i`); ``` any other ways ?

Comment: Yes it won't work. You'll have to create a new regex expression for that. You can do something like this 

    let regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, "i");
    let tagResult = await tagsModel.find({ "tag": regex })


Where searchText is basically your variable and then you can simply use the regex variable inside your find method.